# setting up margin in vb.net while printing

Tags: vb.net, printing, margins

i am developing a school management software in which i have given a small handy functionality of a mini notepad so that it can make notice or doc within the software.
I have taken a RichTextBox for this, Now my problem is that when i enter text in richtextbox without giving space in between ( eg. aaaaaaaa..........) continous for 2 lines and when i click on PrintPreview, it leave some space from it start displaying on left but the text leaves the page from right side.
What i want is that i should a margin on both the side i.e. left & right side.

Below is my code on Print Document Click

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim font1 As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular)

    'Dim formatF As StringFormat = StringFormat.GenericDefault
    'formatF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    'formatF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center


    e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, font:=font1, brush:=Brushes.Black, x:=10, y:=50)


End Sub
```

So it basically do is represented in below images. Please have a look.

[Text in richtextbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8PdT.png)

[Image of print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ibz.png)

Comment: What you're referring to is called word wrap.  In order to achieve this you must call the overload of `DrawString` that takes a `Rectangle` object.  Check [this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/135473-how-to-make-text-auto-adjust-when-printing/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i already referred this website before asking for help over here, but unfortunately i am confused from that website answer.
i know what you are trying to say, basically i need to draw a rectangle first and then have to draw string. but can you help me with my existing code on what to insert and where..

Comment: You don't need to draw a rectangle, you need to create an instance of the `Rectangle` structure that represents the area you wish to print the text in.  `Dim r As New Rectangle(10, 50, 500, 500)  e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, r)`  Alternately, you can use the `e.MarginBounds` property in the `PrintPage` event handler which represents the area in the page within the margins..  Something like this:  `e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print a string within a certain area of the page, specify a `Rectangle` which should contain the string.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1

    Dim pd As PrintDocument

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        pd = New PrintDocument()
        AddHandler pd.PrintPage, AddressOf pd_PrintPage


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim preview = New PrintPreviewDialog()
        preview.Document = pd

        preview.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub pd_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs)

        'Create a long sample string
        Dim s As New String("a"c, 2048)

        'Create a rectangle which describes the area where the string
        'should print
        Dim r As New Rectangle(50, 50, 500, 500)

        'Draw the string
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, r)

        'Since there is no more data to print, set to False
        e.HasMorePages = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir, it really worked. i used e.marginbound solution without using drawrectangle and it work. once again thanks alot for your help.